# EF Core (< 5.0) HasComputedColumnSql - computed on Insert/Update or each query on SQL Server / AzureSQL?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

Note: this question is referencing an *old* EF Core issue.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67335195/1112558) for a discussion relevant to EF Core 5.

I'm seeing conflicting information about this.  [LearnEntityFrameworkCore.com](http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/hascomputedcolumnsql-method) says you can write

```
.HasComputedColumnSql("GetUtcDate()");
```

> The value of the column is generated by the database's GetUtcDate() method whenever the row is created or updated

However, in the [technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx) documentation for computed columns on SQL Server it says:

> Their values are recalculated every time they are referenced in a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. It's unclear from EF Core documentation what type of computed column does `HasComputedColumnSql` represent. Probably because it's a part of the relational extensions, thus is considered provider specific. But since it has no configuration options, I agree that the behavior should be specified.

A quick test with SQL Server shows that the created column is **not** physically stored (no `PERSISTED` option used), and actually it can't since `GetUtcDate` is not deterministic. Hence the `LastModified` example from the first link is incorrect - the column will be recalculated any time it's been read, so it cannot be used for the desired intent, and should be created as normal column and updated by the code.

Looks like the intended usage in EF Core is to allow simple calculation based on other columns like `FullName` or using database specific conversion function with data not stored properly (for instance numeric/date time data stored as text) etc.

Comment: Interestingly, in the EF Core code, including SqlServer specific model factory, computed columns are set/modeled as `ValueGenerated.OnAddOrUpdate`.  I could see value if in the future, they could use this (which users can set via `PropertyBuilder.ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()` extension) to create a trigger for nondeterministic computed columns or to add the `PERSISTED` property to deterministic ones.  Right now, you essentially have to put that trigger in yourself in the migration if you want to emulate this concept.

Comment: Indeed. Until then, `ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate` combined with `HasValueGenerator` and custom `ValueGenerator` class could be used to achieve something like that at client side.

Comment: Or may be not - I can't seem to get the value generator approach working. There are still a lot things to be done in EF Core in order to make it usable :)

Comment: Unfortunately, that strategy doesn't look like it's going to work at all.  Looking into `HasValueGenerator`, it's only called when an entity is added.  Further, they don't have any current plans to change that as seen here: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6999

Answer (score 3):

The two documentation you referenced are correct. Each is talking about different methods. There are several overloads for this method. You can check this over [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalpropertybuilderextensions?view=efcore-5.0) (search for "HasComputedColumnSql" in the browser).

If there are triggers in the database that define values for this column, you will use the `HasComputedColumnSql()` implementation.

If you want to store a computed value on the property, but don't want it to persist in the table, you will use the `HasComputedColumnSql("SomeFunction()")` implementation.

If you want to store the value in a column, you will use the implementation `HasComputedColumnSql("SomeFunction()", stored: true)`.

Comment: Well, the documentation I was referencing is 4 years old :)   If you look at that link you sent, but set the "Version" drop down to EF Core 2.0, you'll see those overloads allowing for `stored: true`  weren't there yet.  

Great to see that this gap has been addressed in the 2 major versions since then!

Comment: I updated title and question to provide clarity for this :) Thanks again for the update!